# UNION ALL, cast NULL as double precision, Postgres

Tags: postgresql

In postgres, I'm getting an error when I try to union two tables where one table has a column (`Amount`) containing `double precision` data type, and the other table does not have a matching column and I'd like the records from that table to just have `NULL` in the `Amount` field.

**Error:**

> "union types text and double precision cannot be matched postgres"

**Pseudo-code:**

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT
   t1.Amount AS 'amount',
   NULL::DATE AS 'date'
FROM Table1 AS t1
UNION ALL

SELECT
   /* next line is the issue */
   NULL AS 'amount',
   t2.Date AS 'date'
FROM Table2 AS t2

) AS FOO
```

I feel fairly certain this solution is a simple casting problem but could not find anything from searching. How do I do the equivalent of `NULL::DOUBLE` in postgres?

**EDIT::POSTERITY**

The accepted answer from @klin and @a_horse_with_no_name's comment that points to a "historical" postgres cast expression `::` where the [syntax is equivalent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS):

```
CAST ( expression AS type )  
expression::type
```

And, here is a list of the [postgres data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Postgres the type `double precision` is also known as `float8` or simply `float`. Use one of them.

```
select null::double precision, null::float;
```

Comment: I ended up using `NULL::INT` and it passed the smell test (once.) Do you have a link to the usage or documentation for this way of casting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @wahwahwah: Surprisingly there is a chapter "Type Casts" in the syntax chapter: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Comment: You might be also interested in [Type Conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv.html).